# Boto DynamoDB error when using attributes_to_get in table.query

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

I've got a DynamoDB database set up with string hash key and range keys. This works:

```
>>> x = table.query(hash_key='asdf@asdf.com', range_key_condition=BEGINS_WITH("20"), 
    request_limit=5)
>>> [i for i in x]
[{u'x-entry-page': ...
```

This doesn't, and I can't figure out why not:

```
>>> x = table.query(hash_key='asdf@asdf.com', range_key_condition=BEGINS_WITH("20"), 
    attributes_to_get=[u'x-start-time'], request_limit=5)
>>> [i for i in x]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/boto/dynamodb/layer2.py", line 588, in query
    yield item_class(table, attrs=item)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto-2.3.0-py2.7.egg/boto/dynamodb/item.py", line 45, in __init__
    raise DynamoDBItemError('You must supply a hash_key')
boto.dynamodb.exceptions.DynamoDBItemError: BotoClientError: You must supply a hash_key
```

This makes very little sense to me. I clearly am supplying a hash key. I can't tell what the issue is just by looking at the Boto source. The attribute in question is definitely present in every record (not that that should throw an error).

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coincidentally, this was just fixed in boto earlier today.  See:

https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/656

Answer (score 2):

With the help of a colleague, we've got it figured out. The problem is that `attributes_to_get` requires the names of the hash and range keys. So, this works:

```
>>> x = table.query(hash_key='asdf@asdf.com', range_key_condition=BEGINS_WITH("20"), 
    attributes_to_get=[u'x-start-time', 'user_id', 'session_time'], request_limit=5)
>>> [i for i in x]
[{u'session_time': u'2012/04/18 09:59:20.247 -0400', u'user_id': u'asdf@asdf.com', 
    u'x-start-time': u'2012/04/18 09:59:20.247 -0400'}, ...
```

This seems like a (minor) Boto issue to me...

Comment: Coincidentally, [issue fixed 3 hours ago](https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/656)!